# VBA convert .doc to .docx Runtime error "-2146959355 (80080005)" on MacOS 12.6

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, file-conversion

I am trying to batch convert a number of Microsoft Word .doc files to .docx files using Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1 on a Mac running macOS 12.6 (21G115).

I'm using this code

```
Sub TranslateDocIntoDocx()
  Dim objWordApplication As New Word.Application
  Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String

  strFolder = "/Users/me/path/to/files/"
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc", vbNormal)
  
  While strFile <> ""
    With objWordApplication
      Set objWordDocument = .Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
          
      With objWordDocument
        .SaveAs FileName:=strFolder & Replace(strFile, "doc", "docx"), FileFormat:=16
        .Close
      End With
    End With
    strFile = Dir()
  Wend

  Set objWordDocument = Nothing
  Set objWordApplication = Nothing
End Sub
```

However I receive an error:

Runtime error "-2146959355 (80080005)".:
Automation error

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Which line of the code gives the error? Why aren’t you running the code in Word?

Comment: Exactly HOW are you running this code?  Do you actually have Word for Mac installed?